# How can I use Github Actions to run Behat tests?

Tags: php, github-actions, behat

I'm attempting to run a suite of Behat tests with Github Actions. I've already configured a workflow that successfully runs some unit tests but to run my Behat tests I require my application to be accessible over HTTP.

Here are the relevant parts of my workflow yaml file:

```
jobs:
  behat:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@verbose
        with:
          php-version: '7.4'
...
      - name: Behat Tests
        run: |
          ACTION_BASE_PATH=`pwd`
          "$ACTION_BASE_PATH"/bin/behat --config behat.github.yml --tags=ci
```

When this runs, I get a curl error each time Behat attempts to access the application over http:

```
      cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException)
    │
    ╳  Unable to access the response before visiting a page (Behat\Mink\Exception\DriverException)
```

Presumably this is because Github Actions has not been configured to serve the application on localhost port 80. The file `behat.github.yml` referenced above configures Behat to make http requests to localhost. I would have thought this would be a common use case with a simple solution and abundant documentation. However, I can find no relevant documentation  on configuring Github actions to run an application accessible over HTTP and I'm beginning to wonder if I've misunderstood something important about the Github Actions functionality.

Comment: Do not know how it is in github actions, but suppose that thre should be webserver running somewhere for applicatuin to be accessible via http. You could try to run php builtin server in another process. But I think using doker would be much more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

The reason curl couldn't connect to localhost on port 80 was that there was no server running. As [Ilia Yatsenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6051839/ilia-yatsenko) suggested, there needs to be a webserver running somewhere.

I ended up modifying my workflow yaml file to look like this:

```
jobs:
  behat:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: shivammathur/setup-php@verbose
        with:
          php-version: '7.4'
...
      - name: Behat Tests
        run: |
          nohup php -S localhost:8081 -t web/ > phpd.log 2>&1 &
          ACTION_BASE_PATH=`pwd`
          "$ACTION_BASE_PATH"/bin/behat --config behat.github.yml --tags=ci
```

The additional line was this one:

```
nohup php -S localhost:8081 -t web/ > phpd.log 2>&1 &
```

This starts the built-in PHP webserver running on localhost:8081 and using `web/` as the document root. Because there's no inbuilt way to run the PHP webserver in the background, I had to use nohup with this command and output all messages to a log file, `phpd.log`.